# jQuery Mobile background not full height

Tags: jquery-mobile

When I load my jQuery Mobile page on an iphone, some of the page extends out of the initial viewport. The space that is out of the initial viewport to begin with is white, not gray which it should be. I've attempted to set the height to 100% using this line of code: `[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}` however this still does not do the trick.

Comment: can you post more codes ? Just 1 line of code can't diagnose the problem .

Comment: My question is simple though. In an ideal situation with no errors in my javascript, how can I set the background of my page to always just be 100% of the html document no matter what the original viewport is. Is my 1 line of code the correct way to do this, and hence you need to see more because an error exists?

Comment: if possible, create a sample at jsfiddle.net. There are a lot of css adjustments and field options that you can set for jQuerymobile and it's hard to predict from your question. Also, is there a reason why you are setting height? Usually the content decides the height of the page and vertical scrolling is natural behavior for mobile

Comment: I found [Jeemusu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087163/content-should-be-filled-from-header-to-footerin-a-html-page) to the question, "jQuery Mobile content should be filled from header to footer" on another stackflow to be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't misuse `!important`. To diagnose what's wrong with the CSS, you can use Firebug in Firefox / Developer Console in Chrome. ( Safari & IE have similar things ). Some CSS may be overridden, or layers maybe overlapped.

Without your HTML codes & jQuery scripts, I can't really help on this, but normally, to make the content to full height, you have to set `html` CSS and `body` CSS to use `height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 2):

I always have the same problem with my JQM pages. I use that to make my page height 100%:

```
$(document).delegate('#yourPage', 'pageshow', function () {
    var the_height = ($(window).height() - $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').height() -   $(this).find('[data-role="footer"]').height());
    $(this).height($(window).height()).find('[data-role="content"]').height(the_height);
});
```

Hope this helps.