# How to develop for tablet using Worklight?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have develop my UI under `common` folder, then I create a skin for my tablet and name it as `android.tablet`. But when I run it on my tablet simulator, it looks like this:

[image]

I use below code in `skinLoader.js`:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var skinName = "default";
//android tablet
if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1 &&
    userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") == -1){
    skinName = "android.tablet";
    alert("tablet!");
}
//android phone
else if(userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1 &&
    userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") != -1){
    skinName = "default";
    alert("default!");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage" class="fullWidth">
    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div class="ui-title">...</div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="fullWidth">Login</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fullWidth{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Why it can't be full screen? Any code I lack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure to [read the Worklight Skins training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_03_Supporting_multiple_form_factors_using_Worklight_skins.pdf)?

The basic premise for Worklight Skins is this:

1. Create a new Worklight project, application
2. Add a skins-supported environment (Android, BlackBerry 6/7/10, iPhone, iPad)
3. For the sake of simplicity, update skinLoader.js to point to the skin's folder ("android.skin" for example)
4. Create a CSS and JS files in the respective folders of the skin
5. Copy the HTML file from common to the skin folder
6. Do whatever you want in the CSS, JS and HTML in the skin folder, like changing color and adding an alart
7. Build all & Deploy
8. Verify the color and alert are displayed, ensuring it is the skin and not default that was loaded.

To preview the skin's web resources:

1. Right-click on the android environment folder
2. Choose Run As >> Preview...
3. Select the skin from the Skin dropdown
4. Click the Run button

You should now see the skin (previewing only displays web resources, not native parts if you have any).

If this fails, you can try altering the URL as follows.
This essentially strips away the MBS container and displays only the web resources.

From:

```
http://localhost:8080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/index.html?webpage=http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/your-app-name/android/1.0/your-skin-name-here/your-html-filename-here.html&devicesFilePath=devices.json&platform=android&ips=169.254.236.125,9.148.205.249,10.0.0.2
```

To:

```
http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/your-app-name/android/1.0/your-skin-folder-name/your-html-filename-here.html
```

This process will hopefully get more streamlined in a future release...

---

As for it being full screen or not, that's completely in the hands of the developer (your CSS, etc), and not Worklight's.

I see you're using jQuery Mobile, look at these:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fullscreen.html
- [How to set header to full screen mode in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732482/how-to-set-header-to-full-screen-mode-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Sorry Idan, based on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857294/jquery-mobile-background-not-full-height),
actually I need to have my fullWidth class for the body and now it works. But do you have any idea how to test the tablet layout in browser? Since browser always loads the common folder :(

Comment: Or maybe can I write something as the path to tablet in Webpage in Mobile Browser Simulator? Original value is: "../apps/services/preview/appTitle/android/1.0/". I have tried change it to "../apps/services/preview/appTitle/android.tablet/1.0/" but it says "The requested path: /appTitle/android.tablet/1.0/ is not supported."

Comment: And by the way, I don't want to test it first in simulator because as you know Android simulator is extremely slow and it slower my development testing too much.

Comment: Thx very much Idan for your support! Btw can you please give a note above indicates that the "test" is a placeholder for the project name? I was mistakenly put the url as it is since I didn't know that the "test" is actually a project name :)

Comment: No problem. :) please mark this question as answered if indeed your questions are now answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to develop for Android tablet make sure that  element in AndroidManifest.xml (inside of Android project) declared that. By default only normalScreens support is set to true.
2. You might need to adjust CSS. By default it has fixed width of 320px and dynamic height, which pretty much is what you have on a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Anton, now it works based on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857294/jquery-mobile-background-not-full-height)..