# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Does the Mobile Browser Simulator support Worklight Skins?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console, worklight-mbs, worklight-skins

I would like to know if the **Mobile Browser Simulator** supports **Skins** using **Worklight 6**.

In a previous discussion found in IBM Worklight forum [Skins does not reflect on Mobile Browser simulator](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014850919) I found that IBM WL 5.0 does not support skins. What about Worklight 6?

Do I have to test it with a emulator/simulator or with a real device?

**P.S.** Until now with my experiments I verified that it does not support skins for the Mobile Browser Simulator. Could you confirm this? It would be appreciated since this will exclude an error in my procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight Console's MBS in v6.0.0.0 does not support displaying Worklight Skins. This will be addressed in [Worklight 6.1.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/rep_ca/0/897/ENUS213-390/ENUS213-390.PDF) (the document does not mention it, but it's included).

You can overcome this, though. I have written the way to do so in this question: [How to develop for tablet using Worklight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850074/how-to-develop-for-tablet-using-worklight/16850246#16850246)

Copy/paste of the relevant part:

To preview the skin's web resources:

1. Right-click on the android environment folder
2. Choose Run As >> Preview...
3. Select the skin from the Skin dropdown
4. Click the Run button

You should now see the skin (previewing only displays web resources, not native parts if you have any).

If this fails, you can try altering the URL as follows.
This essentially strips away the MBS container and displays only the web resources.

From:

```
http://localhost:8080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/index.html?webpage=http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/your-app-name/android/1.0/your-skin-name-here/your-html-filename-here.html&devicesFilePath=devices.json&platform=android&ips=169.254.236.125,9.148.205.249,10.0.0.2
```

To:

```
http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/your-app-name/android/1.0/your-skin-folder-name/your-html-filename-here.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Worklight 6.1 Mobile Browser Simulator supports skin selection for each environment.  The skin can be changed per device from the toolbar above each individual device.
 [image]

Comment: despite adding a skin to an environment. I do not see it listed under the skin dropdown.

Comment: Adding a skin to an environment will require a re-deploy of the Mobile Browser Simulator.  The skin dropdown is not supported from the console, it requires a Run As -> Preview from Eclipse.

Comment: Do we explain this requirement to redeploy the MBS .war file?

Comment: Whenever a new environment or skin is added to a Worklight app, the Mobile Browser Simulator will require another Run As -> Preview from Eclipse to show the updates. Have submitted documentation update for Worklight 6.1 regarding these details.